# Visual studio 2015 error message page with checkbox deletion

Tags: vb.net

I deleted a checkbox on the main form and tried to run. I got the error and from what I can see is I have tried to use the checkbox I deleted but I looked through all the code and its not there. I went to `InitializeComponent()` and don't see the checkbox there. Any one know where I can look to resolve. I assume it was the checkbox deletion but not sure.

Here is the page.

```
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'     the code is regenerated.
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Strict On
Option Explicit On


Namespace My

    'NOTE: This file is auto-generated; do not modify it directly.  To make changes,
    ' or if you encounter build errors in this file, go to the Project Designer
    ' (go to Project Properties or double-click the My Project node in
    ' Solution Explorer), and make changes on the Application tab.
    '
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New(Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationMode.Windows)
            Me.IsSingleInstance = false
            Me.EnableVisualStyles = true
            Me.SaveMySettingsOnExit = true
            Me.ShutDownStyle = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.ShutdownMode.AfterMainFormCloses
        End Sub

        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
        Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
            Me.MainForm = Global.StringProgrammer.Main_From
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Look into your code, not the auto generated code. That auto-generated code does not even belong to a form.

Comment: I understand the error is in the code just cannot find it. thank you for your response.

Comment: what is the specific error? What happens if you double-click on it? That usually takes you to the offending line of code. You might also try to Clean the solution in the Build menu. I've seen weird things like this happen where a clean fixed it.

Comment: Have you looked? Try CTRL+F and search it. Solution-wide search available.

Comment: I closed viasual basic and opended it and the error is gone. Dont know what went wrong. Charles May there was nothing to click but thank you. Jim I will keep CTRL+F for future use thank you.